# Items management in Layout

Tags: javascript, extjs, extjs4

I have a `VBox Layout` and it has two `grid`s as items. My items are displayed continuously in the panel without any space.

Now, I want two things.

1. Adding spacing between the two items.
2. Adding a horizontal separator line between the two items.

I tried adding `splitter` but it makes the grids resizable, which I don't want.

How can I achieve this in Extjs4?

Comment: You can always use CSS to add a margin and a bottom border. The layout engine will consider these and layout correctly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just add some element between these two grids, like this:

```
{
    xtype: 'box',
    autoEl: {
        tag: 'hr'
    }
}
```